# How to prevent orthogonal region transition for error handling

Tags: c++, uml, boost-msm, state-diagram

I want to create the following state machine, with Boost MSM:

[image: Simplified FSM with error states in an orthogonal region]

I would like to be able to prevent the `Error` event to trigger the `AllOk + Error == InError` transition if the orthogonal state is on "B". For example, specifying transition for all orthogonal states would be nice. Something like:

```
{AllOk, B} + Error == {AllOk, A}
```

However, I cannot find how to do it with Boost MSM, neither with regular UML nomenclature, which makes me think I am going the wrong way.

Is there a classic "UML idiomatic" to handle this kind of behavior?

I see two possible solutions:

- Put a guard on `AllOk + Error == InError` which checks if the other state is `B`, [like this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43467828/5682416).
- Send a more specific error (in my case, `CouldNotComputePath`, as I am programming a robot), and somehow transform it in `Error` if it is not handled. I am not really sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find a solution:

The *Error* event can be "catched" in the *MainStateMachine*. If it is not, an internal transition is triggered on the *MainStateMachine*, which will send the *EnterError* event to make the other orthogonal state switch to *InError*.

[image]